# How can I make the correct answers appear with the incorrect answers only once in this quiz app?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, use-state

I am making a quiz app and have the following issue - I have a set of questions and answers in an api array. The question is appearing fine from the below code, however the incorrect and correct answers, which appear separately need to be joined together so I can iterate them as multiple choice answers.

In the below the {incorrect_answers} in the h4 wrapper shows the correct answer twice in the list as well as the incorrect answers. How can I make it so that the correct answer only appears once? Please help!

```
const FirstRound = ({quizArray, setQuizArray, num, setNum}) => {

const {question, id, correct_answer, incorrect_answers} = quizArray[num];
const randNum = Math.round(Math.random() * incorrect_answers.length)+1;
incorrect_answers.splice(randNum, 0, correct_answer)

return <>
<div class="box">
  <h1>Quiz Round One</h1>
    
    <h3>{question}</h3>
    <h4>{incorrect_answers}</h4>
  </div>
  <button onClick={Change}>Next</button>
  </> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part is suspicious:

```
const {question, id, correct_answer, incorrect_answers} = quizArray[num];
const randNum = Math.round(Math.random() * incorrect_answers.length)+1;
incorrect_answers.splice(randNum, 0, correct_answer)
```

It's hard to tell without knowing what the types or values of `correct_answer` and `incorrect_answers` are ; however, I suggest adding `console.log` before and after the `incorrect_answers.splice(randNum, 0, correct_answer)` line, and see what happens if the component is rendered multiple times.

Since [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) mutates Arrays in place, it's possible that you keep modifying the same `incorrect_answers` list (to add the `correct_answer` at each rendering.)

You might need to clone the Array first, or use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn’t cloning the array cause the same problem though? FYI they are in string form

Comment: i think that incorrect_answers are all the options including the correct_answer , slice works  fine.

Comment: @HHHHELP If you clone an array that only contains incorrect answers, and add the correct one inside this array (without modifying the original array) , than at each rendering you'll display a different array, but it will contain the correct answer only once.

Comment: just make this to double check, after this line incorrect_answers.splice(randNum, 0, correct_answer), clean the array for duplicates , const options = incorrect_answers.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return a.indexOf(item) == pos;
});

and then replace {incorrect_answer} for {options} and that's all my friend

Comment: @altoqueperro that's a bit prone to errors (the render function can be called multiple times, in parrallel, from multiple other components, etc...) I would advise against mutating the props at all (either clone it, use slice to create a new answer, change the props outside of the React component, etc...)

Comment: @phtrivier i Agree with you with the clone part and slice, but thats not why the result appear twice